# Tiles refreshing with geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I use geoserver geowebcache for displaying tiles using google maps API. Data comes from Postgis. My problem is that I have to change geometry of some features (not very frequently).

I would like to achieve automation simillar to this from openstreetmap, where after source data change tiles that cover area of changed feature regenerate themselves automaticly. How to do this? Now I have to delete all tiles from geoserver and generate them once again. I do not use pure WMS as service is rather popular and WMS may work slowly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GWC integrated with GeoServer automatically drops the tiles involved when doing a WFS-T transaction in GeoServer.
If you are changing data directly in PostGIS you can look at publishing data change events using a GeoRSS feed:
(Updated URL:) https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/georss.html